# WebRTC: Why "CreateAnswer can't be called before SetRemoteDescription"?

Tags: webrtc

Browser: Chrome

I am trying to debug a webRTC application which works fine on three out of four fronts! I cannot get video from the receiver to the caller. I can get video and audio from the caller to the receiver and audio from the receiver to the caller. The problem is that the receiver does not fire a video (sdpMid="video") ICE candidate. While desperately trying to solve this problem, I tried to use pc.CreateAnswer before setting pc.remoteDescription and it gave the error quoted in the title.

My question is to understand the reason behind this. An answer SDP would just be the SDP based upon the getUserMedia settings/constraints. So, why do we have to wait for setting remoteDescription. I thought that a createAnswer would start firing the gathering of ICE candidates and this can be done earlier without waiting to set remoteDescription. That is not the case. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offers and answers aren't independent, they're part of an inherently asymmetric exchange.

An answer is a direct response to a specific offer (hence the name "answer"). Therefore the peer cannot answer before it has an offer, which you set with `setRemoteDescription`.

An offer contains specific limitations, or envelope (like m-lines), that an answer has to abide by/answer to/stay within. Another way to say it is that the answer is an iteration of the offer.

For instance, an offer created with offer options `offerToReceiveVideo: false` can only be answered with `recvonly` for video (meaning receive video from offerer to answerer only), never `sendrecv`.

Comment: I thought that the offer and answer are merely a description of the media/transport/codec/etc. available at each end and will be analyzed by both ends independently.  I thought that  ICE candidates alone control the ability for SDPs to decide possibility of a communication to be established, which is theoretically possible: If there is no compatibility in the two independent SDPs - no ICE candidates.  However, it makes better sense for the answer to be based upon the offer, as explained by you.

Comment: Offer and answer are descriptions, but the exchange itself is a negotiation. Candidates find ip+port pairs to transport on.

Comment: So onIceCandidate events should not fire at any end until the local and remote SDPs are set at that end?

Comment: @Sam `onicecandidate` fires right after set*Local*Description. It's not tied to setRemoteDescription in any way.

Comment: I rewrote using promises and have posted the entire code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911034/webrtc-using-promises-remote-video-not-seen-at-either-end). You have been a great help. Just one last time, can you take a look at the new code. Now I don't get remote video on either end but I think that the approach of using single code for both caller and receiver and using the Promises was worth the trouble of rewriting.